# Как лучше реализовать масштабирование свеч на графике

Tags: c#, wpf, график, wpf-canvas

Нарисовал свой график на панели `Canvas`.
Как его рисовал я - Есть массив всех свеч, и я вывожу на панель лишь видимый диапазон свеч, т.е. если сдвинуть график в сторону, я с каждой новой свечой рассчитаю новый диапазон видимых свеч, очищаю `Canvas.Children` и данный список выведу на график, добавив в `Canvas.Children`. При таком варианте я могу спокойно настраивать масштаб, при новом расчете я нахожу максимум и минимум свеч и заношу рассчитываю высоту относительно этого. Но данный способ слишком долгий для расчетов. И в итоге логичнее уже на графике хранить сразу все свечи. Но вот проблема заключается тогда в видимом диапазоне. Т.е. надо в массиве `Canvas.Childern` найти нужные свечи и поменять их значения Y и X, значения длины прямоугольников и линий, которые идут вверх и вниз от них. Но будет ли это лаконичным? На сайтах это всё происходит мгновенно, как ни крути. Может кто подсказать пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать это? 2 картинки, с любого сайта и моей программы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, а что если просто вывести все свечи, а потом, при необходимости масштабирования или перемещения вдоль осей, воспользоваться трансформацией?

Comment: @АндрейNOP На счет вывести все свечи, это да. На счет трансформации сейчас почитаю и отвечу, спасибо за совет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите, как можно сделать это с помощью трансформаций. Я буду выводить коллекцию прямоугольников, для вывода буду использовать `ItemsControl`, у которого в качестве `ItemsPanel` будет установлен `Canvas`. `ItemsControl` я оберну в `Border`, чтобы просто обозначить границы графика, ну и потом он еще сыграет свою небольшую роль. Также я размещу 2 кнопки для сдвига "окна" просмотра графика:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
        <ItemsControl Name="Graph">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal"
                Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="&lt;" Padding="2.5,0" Margin="2.5,0"/>
        <Button Content="&gt;" Padding="2.5,0" Margin="2.5,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Надеюсь, здесь для вас всё просто и понятно. Теперь я привяжу к `ItemsControl` коллекцию прямоугольников:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Graph.ItemsSource = new List<Rect>
    {
        new Rect { X = 10, Y = 10, Height = 10, Width = 10},
        new Rect { X = 20, Y = 25, Height = 10, Width = 10},
        new Rect { X = 30, Y = 15, Height = 5, Width = 5},
        new Rect { X = 100, Y = 40, Height = 15, Width = 5},
        new Rect { X = 110, Y = 15, Height = 10, Width = 25},
        new Rect { X = 80, Y = 30, Height = 5, Width = 30},
        new Rect { X = 65, Y = 40, Height = 10, Width = 10},
        new Rect { X = 160, Y = 10, Height = 10, Width = 15},
        new Rect { X = 120, Y = 35, Height = 25, Width = 5},
        new Rect { X = 140, Y = 45, Height = 5, Width = 5}
    };
}
```

Хорошо, если запустить проект, то вы уже увидите эти прямоугольники.

Теперь я с помощью трансформации масштаба увеличу нашу область просмотра, чтобы прямоугольники уже не помещались на экране, добавьте в разметку `ItemsControl`:

```
            <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="5" ScaleY="5"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
```

Теперь добавим в `TransformGroup` еще одну трансформацию - трансформацию сдвига и дадим ей имя, чтобы можно было обращаться из кода:

```
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="GraphTransform"/>
```

Добавим обработчики кликов по кнопкам:

```
private void ButtonLeftClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GraphTransform.X += 10;
}

private void ButtonRightClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GraphTransform.X -= 10;
}
```

В разметке:

```
        <Button Content="&lt;" Padding="2.5,0" Margin="2.5,0" Click="ButtonLeftClick"/>
        <Button Content="&gt;" Padding="2.5,0" Margin="2.5,0" Click="ButtonRightClick"/>
```

Ну и, наконец, для того, чтобы график не выходил за пределы бордера, установим бордеру обрезку по границам: `ClipToBounds="True"`

Готово!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. ваша задача просто "скормить" свою коллекцию фигур элементам, а остальное всё сделает WPF! Пересчитывать фактические размеры фигур вручную не требуется!

Comment: Спасибо большое за пример, буду знать, что такое можно, но, к сожалению, к свечкам это не сильно подходит т.к. там много разных нюансов при масштабировании и сдвиге. Вот есть график, попробуйте его перемещать мышкой и колесом масштабировать, посмотрите, как именно изменяются размеры и в зависимости от чего. Там идет, скорее всего, расчет после каждого сдвига, чтобы в поле зрения находились все видимые свечки с соответствующим масштабом по ценам.
https://smart-lab.ru/g/MOEX%3ASiH8/60/
А так, поставлю галочку конечно за такой труд)

Comment: Ну пересчитывать точно ничего не нужно, главное правильно рассчитать новый масштаб/смещение. По крайней мере я не заметил, чтобы там что-то менялось в самих свечах - чтобы они сливались или распадались на несколько. А вообще, конечно, вы в праве сделать так как хотите.

Comment: Да не то, чтобы я хотел, я думаю, как сделать рационально. Просто, если ты смещаешься и появляется свеча, которая намного выше графика, то весь график должен подстроить под нее, чтобы все свечи уместились в твоём окне. И вот тут как раз таки нужно узнать максимум и минимум свеч и подогнать все значения под высоту Canvasa. Можете поправить, если я не в том направлении думаю. Но я вижу это единственным решением проблемы.

Comment: Ага, ну надо просто как-то вычленить отображаемый в данный момент диапазон и найти на нем самую верхнюю и самую нижнюю точки, затем по ним скорректировать масштаб оси Y. Логики будет побольше, конечно, но заготовка у вас есть. Пробуйте!

Comment: Ну, теперь я хоть понял, в каком направлении смотреть. Буду использовать ваш пример, спасибо!)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, если скормить такому графику допустим 10к элементов, быстро ли будет происходить трансформация? или в wpf нет встроенной оптимизации Canvas

Comment: @Gardes, кто знает? Проверьте :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, это божественно! Для проверки скорости вместо кнопок сделал слайдер. Летает! Пошел писать свою библиотеку для отрисовки графика, спасибо!)

Comment: В скроллвьювер поместили? Или просто привязали `TranslateTransform.X` к значению слайдера? Правда с трансформациями есть проблема, которую нужно учитывать — толщина линий тоже увеличивается при масштабе, что не всегда нужно

Comment: просто привязал TranslateTransform.X к значению слайдера. Пока ничего не увеличивается, работает как окно браузера, размер контента просто обезается

Comment: @Gardes, впрочем, [вот здесь](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42953794#42953794) есть поведение, которое возвращает истинную толщину линий